# Problem with order id after migrating from Magento 1 to 2

Tags: sales-order, migration, sales

Problems with increment_id
We just **migrated from magento 1 to 2**, and when we did a purchase test, the new orders instead **follow the continuation of the last id**, started from the beginning.

Example last order in magento1 migrated to magento 2
300017136

I should continue in the
300017137

But he came out with
300000001

Can someone help me solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

Please open  `sequence_order_1` table.

Changes the increment value  to  **`300017138`**    using MySql query.

Comment: Dear @Amit Bera thanks for your answer, in a clean magento test it works but in this magento 2 that just migrates does not work, when I create a new order puts 300000002 and in BD in the table sequence_order_1 it appears the record 2 on top of which I put in 17137